# My data.table returns a line full of NAs instead of

Tags: r, data.table

Why is this example my data table is still returning a row?

```
> DT = data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a"),v=rnorm(5))
> setkey(DT,x)
> DT
   x          v
1: a  0.2996065
2: a -0.7643157
3: b -1.0991499
4: b  0.1314460
5: b  0.5734016

> DT['c']
   x  v
1: c NA
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `DT["c", nomatch=0L]`. Please go through `?data.table`.